# How to make killall close the terminal that the process is in?

Tags: node.js, bash

So how can I close the terminal where the process is in with killall.

I have tried this:

In 1st terminal:
`killall node`

In 2nd terminal:

```
Ready
Terminated
```

But I want only the 2nd terminal to close after the node is killed.

Comment: I'm not sure this command is available on your system, but you can try `killall process && logout`.

Comment: @ForceBru that isn't what I'm looking for. I want to close the 2nd terminal, not the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-t` option:

```
killall -t $(tty)
```

will call all processes started from the terminal session (even with `nohup`), including the shell.  So, your terminal will get closed.

Comment: -t isn't an option in killall for me. What version of killall are you using?

Comment: I am on a Mac, running Sierra.

Comment: Ok maybe Ubuntu doesn't have that option

Answer (score 0):

You need to also kill the process which runs the terminal, which is usually the parent process of the node process.

The question [How do I get the parent process ID of a given child process?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153976/how-do-i-get-the-parent-process-id-of-a-given-child-process) is a good place to start. You can find the PIDs of the node processes via [How to find the Process ID of a running terminal program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180336/how-to-find-the-process-id-pid-of-a-running-terminal-program).